# Make a field mandatory with validation rules

Tags: validation-rule

Trying to create a validation rule on the Case object in Salesforce. The rule should make the 'TechnicalAssistance__c' field mandatory based on the selected value in the 'EnviarEmailParaAssistencia__c' field (picklist) and also based on a specific classification in the 'Classification__c' field. I have already made a rule:

```
IF( RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Complaint', 
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Classification__c, "ExternalTechnicalAssistance"),
        ISPICKVAL(EnviarEmailParaAssistencia__c, "Sim"),
        ISBLANK(TechnicalAssistance__c)
    ),
    false
)
```

The problem is that, apparently, the rule is being ignored because no error is displayed. Am I overlooking something? I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Double check the API names of the picklist values you're checking. And double check the record type developer name.

Comment: Also, it would be better to rewrite as `AND(RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Complaint', ISPICKVAL(Classification__c, "ExternalTechnicalAssistance"), ISPICKVAL(EnviarEmailParaAssistencia__c, "Sim"), ISBLANK(TechnicalAssistance__c))`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I reviewed the rule related to RecordType.DeveloperName and also tried using RecordType.Id, but it seems that this condition was never met. After remove the condition, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the rule related to RecordType.DeveloperName and also tried using RecordType.Id, but it seems that this condition was never met. After remove the condition, everything works fine.